# Is it possible to make a UICollectionView view horizontal scrolling where first column no moving?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

There is a feature I need to implement is UICollectionView which have tons of cells (products) and should scroll horizontally and vertically. 
There is only restriction is that first column (categories) shouldn't move when user scrolls horizontally but should scroll when user scrolls up and down along with other cells (products). Is it possible to do or I need to choose another UI control?

[image]

Comment: UICollectionView doesn't support this natively. 
You probably need to override customize UICollectionViewFlowLayout  for example -  'layoutAttributesForElementsInRect', 'layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind' and the rest of  UICollectionViewFlowLayout's utilities.

Comment: I don't have time to give you a proper answer right now, but yes, this is possible with UICollectionView.  You can create a subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` and use "sections" as rows, and items as columns.  in `prepareLayout`, you essentially have to calculate the rectangle of your frozen items to keep them pinned in place, and allow the rest to scroll underneath.

Comment: Here's an example:
https://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/uicollectionview-using-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-sticky-rows-and-columns

Comment: yes, this is it. the only addition that my view should have separator (supplementary view ) with text across all cells

Answer (score 0):

While I won't outright say its undoable... I'd recommend breaking things down a bit. It sounds like you have two collections, categories and products and that those two ui elements have different behaviours. Consider using two separate UICollectionViews or alternatively a UIStackView and a UICollectionView.

If you can share more details on the ui you are trying to implement I can try and give you more insight. Right now it sounds like a two view job

Cheers

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: I see. Yeah. In that case you may want to go with the solution by @jlew and make your own subclass of UICollectionViewLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to make it as a separate view?

```
class CategoryCollectionView: UIView {
  private let categoryView = UIView()
  private let collectionView = UICollectionView()
}
```

Then vertical collectionView will be just an ordinary subview in ViewController.
So following it, I'd make something like `ViewController -> CollectionView -> Cells -> { CategoryCollectionView, CategoryCollectionView, TitleLabel }` "Scheme" of UI hierarchy. It's simple and fast

Comment: and how to implement supplementary view with "some text some text" as described on the mockup above? As you can see the text goes across the whole control

Comment: @Sergio Which behaviour do you expect from this view? Which size it should be?

Comment: when user scrolls horizontally then "category" column and "some text" views should be static. But when scrolls up/down then all views should be scrollable

Comment: @Sergio you can send gestureRecogniser-s of the main collectionView (which contains cells with collectionViews) to its cells and require to fail internal collectionView gestureRecognizers. Then main scroll will work only if scroll  of interval collectionView inside wasn't called. Get it?